# jQuery No Conflict Wrapper Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm getting the dreaded `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error in WordPress. I'm pretty sure that I've properly enqueued my jQuery script (it's showing up properly in the footer), and I've used the following no conflict wrapper at the start of my code: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`.

I've tried replacing all $ variables with jQuery. I've also defined `var $j = jQuery;` and replaced all $ variables with $j.

There are other theme-generated jQuery scripts on the page that are working (embedded, not enqueued), so there might be potential conflicts, but I'm not sure how to debug that.

Any help appreciated. I can provide link to the site if that helps.

EDIT

I had this script working perfectly earlier from within the jQuery UI Widgets plugin, but that plugin seemed to be causing serious issues (crashed my site). So I disabled the plugin, and I haven't been able to get the script working since.

Comment: Make sure your script is queued after the jQuery script.

Comment: Try to put the `jQuery` library in `noConflict()` mode, just for the sake of test: `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` after the loading of your `jQuery` library.

Comment: Fabricio, if I understand you correctly, I have done that. jQuery is called on line 828, my script on line 1007.

Comment: bodi0: Should I do that at the beginning of my script, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look quite right. Try this

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("dom is ready");

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, macek. I tried several permutations of that, including stripping out the inner no-conflict wrapper, but no luck. It still doesn't want to recognize the $ variable.

Comment: Perfect... fixed my problem... I was doing $(function ($) {.... not good.

Answer (score 0):

You  could try this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function () {
  ...
  //replacing all Dollar Signs with the j
});
```

That's what worked for me

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, and I was unable to get it to work. I'm really baffled. I have other jQuery working just fine, but not this one. For now I've gone back to running it from the plug-in, which is working, but I would love to have a cleaner solution.